# $matches["x"] works in ISE but not command line shell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have the following Powershell code

```
ls "*.zip" | % {
    $name = $_.name
    if (-not ($name -match '(?<x>\d\d)(?<y>\d{4})\.zip')） { continue }
    $p = $matches["y"] + $matches["x"]
}
```

The code works well in ISE. But it gets the following error if it's run in command line shell.

> ```
> Cannot index into a null array.
> At line:3 char:19
> +     $p = $matches[ <<<< "y"] + $matches["x"]
>     + CategoryInfo           : InvalidOperation: (y:string) [], RuntimeException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
> ```

---

**Edit**
I use `if (-not ...) { continue }` because I didn't want too many braces indent. I corrected the `-not ()` issue. (It's not related to the error though, I tested the files which name are always in the pattern of xxx999999.zip)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It sounds like a scope issue. In ISE, the `$matches` is visible to the code after the `if`. However, in command line shell, it's only visual in the script block of `if`.

Powershell really need to have a strict language definition.

---

However, it's different if all the state is written in one line.

```
ls | %{ $name = $_.name; if (-not ($name -match '(?<d>dip)')) { continue; };  $p = $matches["d"]; "$name : $p"  }
```

Sometime Powershell is just unpredictable.

Comment: PowerShell *has* a language specification. And the language runs the same in the ISE and the command line, actually (minus host cmdlets which act differently). That's the whole point after all.

Comment: Note that your code omits the actual mistake they made. Which is why it works. I'd say the programmer is unpredictable here, not the language.

Comment: Furthermore, the continue abort the pipe the first time a non matching file is found.

Answer (score 3):

**First** a ')' is missing after `.zip'` (maybe a typo)

**Second** just try to add () arround your match

```
ls "*.zip" | % { 
    $name = $_.name 
    if (-not ($name -match '(?<x>\d\d)(?<y>\d{4})\.zip$')) { continue } 
    $p = $matches["y"] + $matches["x"] 
}
```

**Third** your `continue` avoid to process the end of the pipe, you can try

```
ls "*.zip" | % { 
    $name = $_.name;
    Write-Host $name;
    if ($name -match '(?<x>\d\d)(?<y>\d{4})\.zip$'){
    $p = $matches["y"] + $matches["x"] 
    }
}
```

It's also working in a Powershell command line

```
ls "*.zip" | % {$name = $_.name; if ($name -match '(?<x>\d\d)(?<y>\d{4})\.zip$') { $p = $matches["y"] + $matches["x"]}}
```

Comment: Yes, the missing `)` is a typo.

Comment: Just a side comment, that should have little to no effect here: .zip in regex is not really matching .zip -> it matches <anychar>zip. You could probably get rid of it by using basename property and `$` anchor to make sure this digit part is at the end. currently it would also match 1234567zipFooBar.zip

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the `if` and operator precedence:

```
-not $name -match '...'
```

is parsed as

```
(-not $name) -match '...'
```

thus you have

```
'False' -match '...'
```

which doesn't match, thus `$Matches` is empty. In the ISE you probably still had an old `$Matches` lying around from an earlier test.

As an easy solution, just use `-notmatch`:

```
$name -notmatch '...'
```

which does what you'd expect. Or add parentheses around the `-match` operation, but the negated operator is easier imho.

**EDIT:** JPBlanc in his comment on your answer is actually right, the more fundamental problem here is your `continue` which cannot work because it ends the pipeline immediately on the first occasion it applies. So you actually *need* to use the following way:

```
if ($name -match '...') {
  ...
}
```

But of course the problem with your `-not` from above was still one, albeit solving it doesn't help you much.

Comment: JPBlanc, actually, you're right, the `continue` is the problem. So this answer is wrong.